# Dependency Injection with Windows Forms

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I have a very simple C# Windows Forms application that I have decided to convert to use Dependency Injection via Ninject.

The entry point for my application looks like this:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{   
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    // initialize dependency injection
    var kernel = new NinjectKernel();
    kernel.ApplyBindings();
    var form = kernel.GetForm();

    Application.Run(form);
}
```

And my Form looks like this:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private readonly ISomething Something;

    public MainForm()
    {
        Something = new Something(this);

        InitializeComponent();
        CreateControl();
        Something.Init();
    }
}
```

My problem is as follows: I want to call "Something" to do basic initialization work for my Form (e.g. Load grid data, set label text...etc)

However, I only have access to the Form components in my MainForm class. I basically need to inject my MainForm instance into "Something" so that it can apply the modifications.

What I have tried is as follows:

```
public class Something: ISomething
{
    private MainForm Form { get; set; }

    public Something(MainForm form)
    {
          Form = form;
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        Form.Label1.Text = "Change some text!";
    }
}
```

This appears to work, but something tells me that this isn't using DI properly. Can somebody shed more light on the proper approach using DI with Windows Forms?

Comment: I'd probably rather pass 'this' through to something's init:
Something.Init(this); Does ninject not require parameterless constructors?

Comment: No you're right, I was messing around with an attempted solution and forgot to remove the code with error. I updated question to provide what actually works...

Comment: Sorry, I'm even more confused now. The constructor you had previously on MainForm was correct. That should then be assigned to the private readonly Something. The constructor for Something shouldn't have a MainForm parameter. Init should take a MainForm as it's parameter. On the call to Something.Init() pass 'this' (MainForm) through.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying..Is there any better ways you can think of for sake of unit testing? Passing a concrete instance in to Init would be hard to unit test...(e.g. is there a way to be able to mock out the form)..

Comment: I don't work much with forms, but I guess you could create an interface for your forms that you could pass in to Something.Init().